# import in JSP introduce \r\n in generated java file

Tags: jsp, import

In jsp file, these two import statements can introduce two "\n" in the generated java file:

```
<%@ page import="java.net.URLEncoder" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
```

In generated file:
out.write("\r\n\r\n");

How to avoid these new lines? Thanks!

Comment: what are those two import statements ?

Comment: <%@ page import="java.util.Calendar" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>

Answer (score 0):

```
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

paste this code in your web.xml file. It might trim all required space in your html page. So you will need to keep non breaking spaces.

or

```
<%@ page trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
```

paste this code in each jsp page where you want to trim white spaces.